# html picture not showing in JSF template

Tags: html, jsf-2.2

For some reason image etf.jpg will not show up, and i really think it has nothing to do with URL. When I ctrl+ click on the image in NetBeans it showed the picture just fine. Does it have something to do with insert tags?

[!This is file organisation of the project [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSJW7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSJW7.png)

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<style>
    div1{
        position: absolute;
        background-color: lightblue;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 75px;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0px;
        font-weight: bold;
        left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 17%;
        color: lightslategray;
    }
    div2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        font-family: arial;
    }
    div3{
        background-color: red;
        font-family: arial;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0%;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0%;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: lighter;
        height: 15%;
        color: lightslategray;
        text-align: right;
    }

</style>
<h:body>
     <div1>
       <ui:insert name="header">
           <ui:include src = "header.xhtml"/>
       </ui:insert>
   </div1>
    <div2>
        <ui:insert name="content">
            <ui:include src ="defaultContent.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
    </div2>
    <div3>

        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <img src="../img/etf.jpg"/>
            <div4><ui:include src = "contact.xhtml"/></div4>
        </ui:insert>
    </div3>
</h:body>
```

Comment: I think you can debug a lot more... Where is it loaded from, what is the url, what should be the url and more...

Comment: Is there a reason the style is outside of the head?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that templates were in Project>web>templates and other pages were in Project>web. When a template was included in a page url changes, and it i no longer url that is proper for the template. It is now url that works with the page in witch the template is used.

Comment: But this should have been fairly visible in a 404 in the browser and server, right? Did you check these things before posting the question?